# How can view both the text file and image file inside the email by using smtplib

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
html = html_table + html_table1

import smtplib

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
import datetime

me = "sender@gmail.com"
you = ['receiver@gmail.com']

subject = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("[%A %I:%M %P]")

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = subject
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = ",".join(you)

msgText = MIMEText('<b>Some <i>HTML</i> text</b> and an image.<br><img src="cid:image1"><br>Nifty!', 'html')

filename = ("/home/EA.png")
attachment = open(filename,"rb")
msgImage = MIMEImage(attachment.read())

part1 = MIMEText(html, msgText, 'html')
html = html_table + html_table1
part = MIMEBase("application","octet-stream")
part.set_payload((attachment).read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
encoders.encode_base64(msgImage)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment; filename= '+filename)
msgImage.add_header('Content-ID', '<image1>')

msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(msgImage)

s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
s.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

How can view both the text file and image file inside the email by using smtplib -> Here the first one is embedded in the email and 2nd one is comming as attachement

For example in the above code msg.attach(part1) -> is embedded in the email while msg.attach(msgImage) -> this is coming as an attachement. 
I want to embed both the attachments inside the email. Can someone please tell me what I am missing here please

Answer (score 0):

```
msgText = MIMEText('<b>Some <i>HTML</i> text</b> and an image.<br><img src="cid:image1"><br>Nifty!', 'html')

We can edit it here as per the requirement
```